# How do I get more planets to explore?

Tags: epic-astro-story

I have explored both Octopi and R-Type fully, and brought back almost all of the settlers from both planets.

How do I get even more planets to explore? I could definitely use more settlers on my planet!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to unlock more planets to explore, you first need to discover their location on your planet as you did for the R-Type. After you find them, they will ask you for help in ridding their world of space pirates. After you take care of the pirates, you are free to explore their world in addition to receive tourists from them.